# How to create multiple lists from data frame column value

Tags: python

df1

```
    Ticker          Category
0      XOM           Group 1
1      CVX           Group 1
2  RDSA-GB           Group 2
3    BP-GB  Group 1, Group 2
4  EQNR-NO           Group 3
5    FP-FR           Group 4
6   ENI-IT  Group 3, Group 4
7      COP           Group 5
```

The result I'm going for would create lists of 'Ticker' based on the 'Category' column and name that list the 'Category' value while replacing spaces with "_"

Secondly, if there's an instance where Category has two values, such as "US Major, Euro Major" then how could i make sure that "Ticker" ends up in both Category lists?

```
Group_1 = ['XOM','CVX','BP-GB']
Group_2 = ['RDSA-GB','BP-GB']
Group_3 = ['EQNR-NO','ENI-IT']
Group_4 = ['FP-FR','ENI-IT']
Group_5 = ['COP']
```

Thanks!

Comment: If the 'Category' contains multiple values then will they have underscores in their values?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, i fixed the above - no they won't

Comment: name the list ? you mean like a dictionnary ?

Answer (score 2):

Well you said name the list, I think you mean in a dictionary way? If it is the case try this :

```
import pandas as pd

df =  pd.DataFrame([["XOM","US Major"],
["CVX","US Major"],
["RDSA-GB","Euro Major"],
["BP-GB","Euro Major"],
["EQNR-NO","Euro Major"]],columns=["Ticker","Category"])

df_to_lists = df.groupby("Category")["Ticker"].apply(list)
lists_to_dict = dict(df_to_lists)
print(lists_to_dict)
```

output :

```
{'Euro Major': ['RDSA-GB', 'BP-GB', 'EQNR-NO'], 'US Major': ['XOM', 'CVX']}
```

If you don't want the dictionary, the df_to_lists outputs :

```
Category
Euro Major    [RDSA-GB, BP-GB, EQNR-NO]
US Major                     [XOM, CVX]
Name: Ticker, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the power of loops like this (I assume my `df` is your `df1`):

```
lists_with_unique_vals = dict()
for cat in df.Category.unique():
    lists_with_unique_vals[cat.replace(' ', '_')] = list(df[df['Category']==cat]['Ticker'].unique())
```

The result is following:

```
>> print(lists_with_unique_vals)
{'US_Major': ['XOM', 'CVX'], 'Euro_Major': ['RDSA-GB', 'BP-GB', 'EQNR-NO']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @nassiam's code to handle cases where there can be multiple categories,

```
import pandas as pd

df =  pd.DataFrame([["XOM","US Major"],
["CVX","US Major"],
["RDSA-GB","Euro Major"],
["BP-GB","Euro Major"],
["EQNR-NO","Euro Major"],
["ABC-XYZ", "Euro Major, US Major"],
["DEF-GHI", "Euro Major, US Major"]], columns=["Ticker","Category"])

df_to_lists = df.groupby("Category")["Ticker"].apply(list)
lists_to_dict = dict(df_to_lists)
print(lists_to_dict)

# Till here it is the same code as @nassiam pointed out

# To handle multiple-valued category
keys = lists_to_dict.keys()
for key in keys:
    categories = [x.strip() for x in key.split(',')]
    if len(categories) > 1:
        for cat in categories:
            if cat in lists_to_dict:
                lists_to_dict[cat] += lists_to_dict[key]
            else:
                lists_to_dict[cat] = lists_to_dict[key]
        lists_to_dict.pop(key, None)

# To replace space with underscore
for key in lists_to_dict:
    lists_to_dict[key.replace(" ", "_")] = lists_to_dict.pop(key)
```

It is under the assumption that the first column `Ticker` has unique values. Otherwise, when appending the lists use `set` to make them unique.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Ranka - you're correct in the assumption that the first column Ticker has unique values. How would you adjust the code if "Category" column has 10 unique values, any of which might be combined? ... for example your code works well for 'US Major' and 'Euro Major' ... but what if there are also Categories 'Permian', 'Multi', and 'Permian, Multi' ... the result would need the 'Permian, Multi' Ticker to appear in each the Permian and the Multi lists, but not result in a 'Permian, Multi' list (which is what is currently happening using the above). Thanks!

Comment: so you want the ticker to be present for all three, 'Permian', 'Multi' and 'Permian, Multi', right?
If that's the case then there can be two ways but that is like a requirement I guess. Either you should know what are the possible categories beforehand or have a different separator to identify subcategories. For example, 
`"US Major, Euro Major, 'Permian, Multi'"`. 
In this case, first level contains overall categories and then you can split inside the single-quote to identify the subcategories.

Comment: thanks for the follow-up. Similar to the US Major and Euro Major... I want the 'Permian, Multi' Ticker to show up in two 'Permian' and 'Multi' ... and there not to be a 'Permian, Multi' list .... similar to how in your code above the result is only 'US Major' and 'Euro Major' ... there is no 'US Major, Euro Major'

Comment: Oh! Just remove the line where I pop the keys (`lists_to_dict.pop(key, None)`). It won't remove the key `US Major, Euro Major` from the dictionary in that case.

Comment: Sorry to rephrase - - i want to exclude "US Major, Euro Major" (so the original code is correct) ... and also exclude "Permian, Multi" (and any other multi category reference). Thanks!

Comment: You have to give an example. I didn't get that. Just to clarify, in case you want to handle any type of multiple category cases, it can handle that. Whether there are 2, 3 or 100 categories, all can be taken care of.

Comment: Can you try the code I posted as the answer? It works on the updated example as well.